# How to determine selection of an instance based on the associated instance in a 1:M relationship?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two models `Task` and `TaskMember`

**Task**
id: Primary key
added_by: Foreign key to user
title

**TaskMember**
id: Primary key
task_id: Foreign key to task
member_id: Foreign key to user

Both these model are associated using 1:M relationship.

In order to fetch all the tasks added by a user with there members i write the query as:

```
let tasks= await Task.findAll( { where: { added_by: user.id }, include : [ { model: TaskMember, as:"members" } ] } )
```

Now I want to only fetch those tasks where the tasks members do not have `member_id` same as the task `added_by`
I tried to achieve using the following query

```
let tasks= await Task.findAll( { 
                             where: { added_by: user.id }, 
                             include : [ { 
                                                 model: TaskMember, as:"members", 
                                                 where: { member_id: {[Op.ne]: user.id } } 
                                             } ] 
                  } )
```

But this query selected all the tasks and did not selected the task member instance where `member_id` was equal to `user.id`

I wanted to ignore the task as a whole.Please guide me on how to achieve my requirement.

Comment: If you want to filter tasks by TaskMember records and have all TaskMember records with each task that was filtered than you need to use a literal with raw SQL in the main `where` option like `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from TaskMember tm where tm.task_id=Task.id and member_id=@userid)`